# What is updated with "Update Root Certificates" enabled? What is the equivalent in Windows 2008R2?

Tags: windows, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

What root certificates are/are not updated when the following checkbox is checked?

[image: Update Root Certificate image]

**Additional questions**

- If I manually remove a root certificate, will this service replace that very certificate?
- What is the equivalent in Windows 2008R2/Win7, I can't find the setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this page:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125

I think it will answer some of your questions. It even contains some information regarding different operating systems.

Specifically, here is the list of what's updated in the Windows Root Certificate Program:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2592.aspx